# Babel - Import a function from a JS file and use it in a React component in another JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

(Babel libraries and ReactDOM are in the HTML file)

regin.js

```
function hello(){
    alert("hello");
}
export default hello;
```

hello.js

```
import hello from "./regin";

class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    doit = () => {
        hell();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                 <img alt="userimg" onClick={this.doit} src={this.props.img}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This gives me errors:
*Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined*

and
*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.*

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What do you mean by that, "(Babel libraries and ReactDOM are in the HTML file)"?

Comment: @Mateen React environment and webpack are not previously installed but I'm using the in-browser Babel transformer - ReactDOM is called in the HTML file.
(Just trying to provide all the - maybe relevant - information to know which piece of puzzle doesn't fit)

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
import {hello} from "./regin";
```

Comment: He exported the function as default. why he should try named import?

Comment: This would do nothing but create *another* error. He's using default exports, not named exports. I recommend deleting the answer.